# Internal server error when I try to get product name $product->get_name()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I get a Internal server error when I try to get product name with the following code :

```
// I get product ID from the database in the $product_id variable

$product_factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
$product         = $product_factory ->get_product($product_id);
```

I get this error :

> "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   get_name() on boolean in ..."

Comment: The code you've shown us does not contain "get_name(". Your error is happening somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

just add **if statement** before calling `get_name()` function as probably  at some point your query is not returning the product id and that's mean you product is `null` and you can't call `get_name()` on null that's why you are getting this error.

so your code should be like this:

```
$product_factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
$product = $product_factory->get_product($product_id);
if ($product) {
    echo $product->get_name();
}
```